# How to override Control.Invalidate() method?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drawing, controls

I use `OwnerDrawAll` properties for my control:

```
this.customTreeView.DrawMode =System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawAll;
this.customTreeView.DrawNode += 
    new System.Windows.Forms.DrawTreeNodeEventHandler(customTreeView_DrawNode);

private void customTreeView_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e) {
   if(!myComboBoxChanged) {              // Draw the whole control(tree and info)
        drawNode(e);
        drawInfo(e);
   } else {                              // Draw only info
        drawInfo(e);
   }
}
```

Then I use text changed event:

```
private void cBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            text = cBox.Text;                 // I need this in drawInfo()
            myComboBoxChanged = true;
            this.customTreeView.Invalidate();  // It doesn't do what I want
            myComboBoxChanged = false;
    }
```

Here `Invalidate()` method redrawing the whole tree, how can I fix this so only `drawInfo()` will be called ?

Comment: You are trying to optimize a bug.  Drag the window off the screen and back on to see your DrawNode event fail to draw properly.

Comment: @Hans Passant, Is there any way to do it correctly, I mean to draw only part of my control ?

Comment: I shoudn't use `.Invalidate` method. I tried to use `.Refresh` method, it redraw info part, but other part (`drawNode()`) becomes white and everything  in this part disappeared, please help me

Comment: This doesn't get better until you fix the buggy DrawNode method.  You will need to get rid of myComboBoxChanged in that code.

Comment: @Hans Passant, could you tell me then how I need to implement that kind of code (when I need to redraw only part of control)

Comment: @William: you are misunderstanding Invalidate(). It will not directly cause a redraw, but sends a message behind the scenes, which will trigger a redraw sometime later (after cBox_TextChanged returns), so there is no use trying to set a bool flag around your call. If you really want to "optimize" this (why?), Invalidate() has overloads that allow you to specify a rectangle/region to invalidate.

Answer (score 0):

the better way is to create your own TreeView Class and encapsulate all of your methods and properties so :

```
public class MyTreeView : TreeView
{
    public bool TextBoxChanged { get; set; }
    public MyTreeView()
    {
        DrawMode = TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawAll;
        DrawNode += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawTreeNodeEventHandler(customTreeView_DrawNode);


    }
    protected override void OnInvalidated(InvalidateEventArgs e)
    {
        //comment  the below line to create your own Invalidate
        //base.OnInvalidated(e);
    }

    private void customTreeView_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!TextBoxChanged)
        {              // Draw the whole control(tree and info)
            drawNode(e);
            drawInfo(e);
        }
        else
        {                              // Draw only info
            drawInfo(e);
        }
    }


    private void drawNode(DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        //...........
    }

    private void drawInfo(DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        //...........
    }
}
```